# Fitting four columns inside 940 pixels

Tags: css, html

I am trying to fit four columns inside a container whose width is 940px http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/D3Z6g/ but the columns do not exactly fit.Each column has 220px and a right margin of 20px,so ideally they should fit well if i remove the right margin for the last column but even after that,they wont fit.The last column is shorter by 12px.

My browser is firefox 12

here is the html

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="uft-8">
<title>Four Columns Portfolio</title>
<style type="text/css">

.container{
width:940px;
border:1px dotted red;
height:auto;
}
li.portfolio{
display:inline-block;
width:220px;
height:180px;
background-color:orange;
margin-right:20px;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
li.every-forth{
background-color:orange;
width:208px !important;
margin-right:0;
}
.portfolio-div{
display:block;
margin-left:-40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
   <div class="portfolio-div">
         <ul>
         <li class="portfolio">
         <p>Column 1</p>
         </li>
         <li class="portfolio">
         <p>Column 2</p>
         </li>
         <li class="portfolio">
         <p>Column 3</p>
         </li>
         <li class="every-forth portfolio">
         <p>Column 4</p>
         </li>
         </ul>  
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why have you set the fourth column to be shorter?

Comment: Since i want four columns on one row.

Comment: You will have more flexibility using percentages. And you will have 940px to play with - (220px * 4)+(20 * 3) = 940

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the space between `inline-block` (like `inline`) elements.
To avoid this problem you have 2 options :

1. Remove the space by adding a HTML comment between the `<li>`s

   ```
   <li class="portfolio">
       <p>Column 1</p>
   </li><!--
   --><li class="portfolio">
       <p>Column 2</p>
   </li>
   ```
2. Remove the space between the `<li>`s

   ```
   <li class="portfolio">
       <p>Column 1</p>
   </li><li class="portfolio">
       <p>Column 2</p>
   </li>
   ```

But because it's `<li>`, [they don't need to be closed](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags), so you can do that :

```
<li class="portfolio">
    <p>Column 1</p>
<li class="portfolio">
    <p>Column 2</p>
```

I made a little [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Calou/HcuAw/) some times ago which can help you understand what I'm saying.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work using html5 like this

```
<!Doctype html>
<head>
<meta charset="uft-8">
<title>Four Equal Columns</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:box;
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    box-orient:horizontal;
    width:940px;
    margin-left:3%;
    border:1px dotted red;
}

.column {
    -moz-box-flex:1;
    -webkit-box-flex:1;
    box-flex:1;
    width:220px;
    margin-right:20px;
    background-color:#ddd;
}

.column p {
    background-color:orange;
    height:auto;
}
.every-forth{
margin-right:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="column">
        <p>Column 1"</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <p>Column 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <p>Column 3</p>
    </div>
     <div class="column every-forth">
        <p>Column 4</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/thiswolf/YNf9N/